# Convert Javascript regex to Typescript regex

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript, regex-negation

I have a regex which checks the inputText is in valid url format or not.
And working almost good:

```
checkUrlFormat() {
    const pattern = /^(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)?(?:(?!(?:10|127)(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!(?:169\.254|192\.168)(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:\/\S*)?$/;

    if (pattern.test(this.inputText) || this.inputText == null) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

But i need to make that pattern shorter so I have written a regexp in https://www.debuggex.com/#cheatsheet as

**`(((http|https)(://))?((www).)?)[a-z0-9]+(.|[a-z0-9])+[a-z0-9]`**

but it is in javascript format and i could not find how to use that string with the code above. When i directly copy paste it, it is giving syntax error. How can i combine them.

Comment: Try escaping the forward slashes from `(://)` to `(:\/\/)` for the syntax error.

Comment: You can even shorten this: '(http|https)' to: 'https?' like in your original regex (save a few bytes)

Comment: How about IDN (International Domain Names) urls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
checkUrlFormat() {
    const pattern = /^(((http|https)(:\/\/))?((www).)?)[a-z0-9]+(.|[a-z0-9])+[a-z0-9]$/;

    if (pattern.test(this.inputText) || this.inputText == null) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```